# Kali Linux 2020.4 Not Going Into Monitor Mode

Tags: wireless-networking, terminal, kali-linux

I was first using Kali 2020.3, and had to manually install my wireless driver (RTL8822BE). After that, monitor mode would work on it with the command `sudo airmon-ng start wlan0`. I decide to upgrade to Kali 2020.4 and it automatically had my wireless driver so connecting to WiFi wasn't a problem. The part that is the problem though is putting the WiFi card into monitor mode. I've tried `sudo airmon-ng check kill` to turn off the WiFi network and tried `sudo airmon-ng start wlan0` to put the wireless card into monitor mode, but it automatically switches back to wlan0, and not wlan0mon. Even when I run the command `sudo iwconfig`, I get wlan0 and not wlan0mon. I don't ever see wlan0mon even when it's doing the command. I've tried reinstalling my WiFi driver and it doesn't change anything. I also have the problem of getting my internet back because when I use the command `sudo airmon-ng check kill`, it kills the WiFi process. I tried to use `sudo service NetworkManager restart` and it doesn't work (but the command itself works). The only way I am able to get WiFi back is to reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this still works for 2020.4 (since I'm on the weekly release of Kali), but I've found an answer.

To put your network card into monitor mode, first you have to stop the NetworkManager service (and for me doing `sudo ifconfig wlan0 down` will work to turn off the WiFi card for a second, then automatically turn itself back on even without using the command `sudo ifconfig wlan0 down`). To stop the NetworkManager run the command `sudo service NetworkManager stop`.

Secondly, you have to enable monitor mode. This can be done in 2 ways (maybe more but I don't know them), and that is running the command `sudo airmon-ng start wlan0`, or you can run the command `sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor` (but this method doesn't seem to work as I've tried capturing packets and didn't get anything). To check if you are in monitor mode, run the command `iwconfig` (and even though it may not say wlan[#]mon it will say the mode it is in from the text `Mode: "Your current mode"`.

Thirdly, to put your network card back into managed mode, run `sudo ifconfig wlan0 down`, `sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode managed`, then run `sudo service NetworkManager start` and it should work.